# how to calculate the confidence interval when sum the predictions

Tags: confidence-interval, prophet

I want to predict the total sales of 10 stores. 8 of the 10 stores have 10 years sales data available, while the other 2 stores only have 2 and 4 years sales data.

Firstly, I use prophet to build one model with 10 years sales data to predict the total sales of the 8 stores, with 0.95 confidence interval.

Then, I use prophet to train the second model for the store that only have 2 years data, then train the third model for the store that only has 4 years data with 0.95 confidence interval.

To get the total sales of the 10 stores, I need to sum the predicted sales of the 3 models. My question is "how to calculate the confidence interval of the total sales?"

Thanks